# How to enable testing for DeprecationWarning and PendingDeprecationWarning using tox+pytest

Tags: pytest, tox

Over the years I have been testing `ruamel.yaml` with `tox` and `pytest` on a regular basis for multiple versions of Python. Soon after the first Python 3.7 beta got out I included that and upgraded testing against the release version of 3.7 when that was released. I have been still been doing most of my day-to-day work however with Python 3.6 (and 2.7 where necessary).

I was therefore quite surprised to get an issue logged on bitbucket, for a `DeprecationWarning` because `ruamel.yaml` was still importing things from `collections` the Python 2.X way (starting 3.8 these **have** to be imported from `collections.abc`, where they already live). I would have expected that my `tox` runs, which are a mandatory prerequisite in my toolchain for being able to push a new version to PyPI, to have caught on this a few months ago.

From the commandline you can see the warnings, e.g. when you do:

```
python3.7 -W always -c "import ruamel.yaml"
```

After some researching I added:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    error::DeprecationWarning
    error::PendingDeprecationWarning
```

to my `tox.ini`, which did not change test results for target `py37` (321 passes/2 skipped/7 xfail).

Then I added:

setenv =
    PYTHONWARNINGS=error

to the default (`[testenv]`) target. That gave some interesting changes in the result, as testing crashed because of Deprecation warnings in the `tox`/`pytest`/`virtualenv` toolchain itself.

I fixed those by hand (intending to automate that after a clean `tox -r` run), to see if going through with this would at least get an error on tox for `ruamel.yaml` itself, but it didn't. If you instead add:

```
setenv =
    PYTHONWARNINGS=always::DeprecationWarning
```

to `[testenv]` you'll see that the toolchain has:

> DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
>   DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib
>   DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working

That last one is actually is what I was looking for but those error was because of code in the tox dependency pyparsing...

Then I new file `test_import.py` with a single test:

```
def test_import():
    from ruamel.yaml
```

and double checked that `tox` executes the test (322 tests passing), **but no message or warning are displayed**, not even when adding `-ra` to `pytest`.

I had been expecting `tox` to help me find deprecations early on, but in fact it seems impossible to get them to trigger at all. I can of course add the commandline shown above, as additional command in my `tox.ini`. But some deprecation might not be so easily triggered and I don't want to duplicate my test effort, just to catch potential deprecations.

How can I trigger the `DeprecationWarning` in my code using `tox`?

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a minimal `test_one.py`

```
def test_one():
    from collections import Hashable
```

a simple `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name="depwarntest",
        version="0.0.1",
        description="test to get DeprecationWarning in code on 3.7",
        long_description = "more details soon",
        author_email="a.van.der.neut@ruamel.eu",
        author="Anthon van der Neut",
        license="MIT",
        url="",
        packages=find_packages(),
    )
```

And a basic `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py37,py36,py27

[testenv]
commands =
    /bin/bash -c 'pytest test_*.py'
deps =
    pytest

[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    error::DeprecationWarning
    error::PendingDeprecationWarning
```

and run `tox`, you'll get a nice clean exception because of your `import`:

```
==================================================================================== FAILURES =====================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________ test_one _____________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_one():
>       from collections import Hashable

test_one.py:6: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1032: in _handle_fromlist
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

name = 'Hashable'

    def __getattr__(name):
        # For backwards compatibility, continue to make the collections ABCs
        # through Python 3.6 available through the collections module.
        # Note, no new collections ABCs were added in Python 3.7
        if name in _collections_abc.__all__:
            obj = getattr(_collections_abc, name)
            import warnings
            warnings.warn("Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead "
                          "of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, "
                          "and in 3.8 it will stop working",
>                         DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
E           DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working

.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py:52: DeprecationWarning
============================================================================ 1 failed in 0.31 seconds =============================================================================
```

on `py37`, whereas `py36` and `py27` run fine.

Interestingly enough if you change the test file to read

```
from collections import Hashable    

def test_one():
    from collections import Hashable
```

running `tox` will run fine on `py37` as well. **And this even is the case if you move that module level import to another `test_XYZ.py` file**.

For `ruamel.yaml` this means that all the module level imports of `ruamel.yaml` in the test files need to be moved to methods/functions; that any root level classes in the test that depend, e.g. on `ruamel.yaml.YAML()` need to use a generator; and that the module level `yaml_object()` needs to be handled in a special way as well.

An extra `tox` target helps to test gradual move by doing conformance testing:

```
# deprecation warning fail
[testenv:dwf]
basepython = python3.7
commands =
    /bin/sed 's/collections.abc/collections/' -i .tox/dwf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/comments.py
    /bin/bash -c 'pytest --maxfail=2 _test/test_[a-cz]*.py'
```

Here the already corrected source `comments.py` is reverted, just for the modules that have been adapted are tested. `ted -e py37,dwf` should pass the first (once more with 321 test passing) and fail on the second target.

Comment: For the subclassing of `YAMLObject`, which only works on top-level classes, I reverted to writing out a file to the temporary directory and then running the file with `check_output(sys.executable, tmp_file)`.